# temperature string to int c#

Tags: c#, string, int

I want to be able to use 2 progress bars as temp gauges for a winform I am making. the temps are for the cpu & gpu of my PS3. I have a label at the moment for each (CTemp & GTemp) which shows the temp as 70 C (for example)

what I want to do is to get that 70 from the string to an int so that I can use it as a `progressbar1.Value` I have tried the simple things ( I am a bit of a noob) like `int.Parse` or `int cputemp = convert.toint32(CTemp.Text);`

Obviously it is completely wrong, but this is what I have in a button at the moment

```
string cputemp = PS3.CCAPI.GetTemperatureCELL();
string gputemp = PS3.CCAPI.GetTemperatureRSX();
progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(cputemp);
progressBar2.Value = int.Parse(gputemp);
```

Anyways, any ideas would be great. Thanks

Comment: if it's always in the same format (i.e a number with a `C` at the end) you can do something like `int temp = int.Parse(CTemp.Text.Replace(" C", string.Empty));`

Comment: Or you can use a different method to get the temps:
`TargetInfo targetInfo = null;
if (PS3.GetTargetInfo(out targetInfo) >= 0)
{
    progressBar1.Value = targetInfo.TempCell;
    progressBar2.Value = targetInfo.TempRSX;
}` No need to parse/use regex etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the string to an integer once you've stripped out all non-numeric characters from the string.  There are probably lots of ways to do that, this one should do the trick:

```
string cputemp = PS3.CCAPI.GetTemperatureCELL();
cputemp = Regex.Replace(cputemp, "[^0-9]", string.Empty);

progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(cputemp);
```

---

You might also use `TryParse` in case something goes wrong, so you can handle the error.  Something like this:

```
int cputempvalue = 0;
if (int.TryParse(cputemp, out cputempvalue))
    progressBar1.Value = cputempvalue;
else
    // integer parsing failed, handle the error here
```